# Error in location :getLocation() method cannot be called from event thread

Tags: blackberry, error-handling, gps, location

What I want to do is have the a map open with the click of a buttonfield with two Criterias, the user must either specify the location and then the image must be added to the location otherwise the Image must be added to the users current location.

The problem I am having is adding both criterias into an if statement in a thread / new thread or even in a FieldChangeListener.

The error I keep getting is:

> Error in location :javax.microedition.location.LocationException:
> getLocation() method cannot be cal[0.0] led from event thread [0.0]
>
> Error in location :getLocation() method cannot be called from event
> thread

My code:

```java
FieldChangeListener Listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        ButtonField buttonClicked = (ButtonField) field;
        if ((buttonClicked.getLabel()).equals("Push")) {
            CustomMapField mMapField;
            Coordinates mCoordinates;
            BlackBerryCriteria blackBerryCriteria = null;
            BlackBerryLocation blackBerryLocation = null;
            BlackBerryLocationProvider blackBerryLocationProvider = null;
            double Doublelat = 0.0;
            double Doublelng = 0.0;
            blackBerryCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria();
            if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE)){
                    blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE);
            }else if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST)){
                blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST);
            }else if(GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS)){
                blackBerryCriteria.setMode(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_AUTONOMOUS);
            }else{
                blackBerryCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                blackBerryCriteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
            } try {
                blackBerryLocationProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider) BlackBerryLocationProvider.getInstance(blackBerryCriteria);
                blackBerryLocation = (BlackBerryLocation) blackBerryLocationProvider.getLocation(60);
                QualifiedCoordinates qualifiedCoordinates = blackBerryLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates();
        
                Doublelat = qualifiedCoordinates.getLatitude();
                Doublelng = qualifiedCoordinates.getLongitude();
                mCoordinates = new  Coordinates(Doublelat, Doublelng, 0);
                mMapField = new CustomMapField();
                mMapField.mIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("coin_silver.png");
                mMapField.moveTo(mCoordinates);
                mMapField.setZoom(1);
                add(mMapField);
             }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Debug 5");
                System.out.println("Error in location :"+e.toString());
                System.out.println("Error in location :"+e.getMessage());
             }
        }
    }
};

public class CustomMapField extends MapField {
    Bitmap mIcon;
    XYRect mDest;

    public void moveTo(Coordinates coordinates) {
        super.moveTo(coordinates);
        mDest = null;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        if (null != mIcon) {
            if (null == mDest) {
                XYPoint fieldOut = new XYPoint();
                convertWorldToField(getCoordinates(), fieldOut);
                int imgW = mIcon.getWidth();
                int imgH = mIcon.getHeight();
                mDest = new XYRect(fieldOut.x - imgW / 2, 
                fieldOut.y - imgH, imgW, imgH);
            }
            graphics.drawBitmap(mDest, mIcon, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The error Is with the following line `add(mMapField);`

```java
  Doublelat = qualifiedCoordinates.getLatitude();
  Doublelng = qualifiedCoordinates.getLongitude();
  mCoordinates = new  Coordinates(Doublelat, Doublelng, 0);
  mMapField = new CustomMapField();
  mMapField.mIcon=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("coin_silver.png");
  mMapField.moveTo(mCoordinates);
  mMapField.setZoom(1);
  add(mMapField);

  /*MapView mapView = new MapView();
    mapView.setLatitude(finalintlat);
    mapView.setLongitude(finalintlng);
    mapView.setZoom(10);
    MapsArguments mapsArgs = new MapsArguments(mapView);
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, mapsArgs);
```

Please advise me more in detail how to do so, and please give an example; I can't understand how as "mMapField" is a custom MapField and "mapView" is a class Mapview (please see my code snippet above).

Comment: Just let me know, Is your application not responding when fetching the location ..?

Answer (score 2):

Obtaining a location is a time-consuming task, it can take as much as 1 minute even with good satellite visibility, although newer berries have improved a lot the time-to-first-fix (TTFF).

Time consuming tasks, like opening connections, or obtaining a fix, should not be performed in the event thread, because this thread has to respond to user events, and if you hog it, then the GUI frozens. And everything running inside `fieldChanged` runs in the event thread. So it is a good thing RIM implemented a thread detection in its new BlackBerryLocationProvider and throws exceptions, now you are aware of the bad design and can take corrective measures.

You have several options to get a fix asynchronously:

1. Use [LocationListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationListener.html).
2. Spawn a new thread.
3. Preemtively obtain a fix long before you need it (or at regular intervals), then you'll have it quickly available when the button is pressed, (either retrieving it from somewhere you previously saved it or calling `LocationProvider.getLastKnownLocation`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments(mMapField));` in place of `add(mMapField);`

Comment: @ Anzy_  the code fetches the longitude and latitude, there is just a problem with the way I am placing everything. if I take everything out and only use the code to get "My location"(using the code in mainscreen) then it works perfectly.

Comment: @Coral Doe, please see the changes I have Made on my post, than you

Comment: The correct Way of fixing this issue was by adding the following in to my code: 'synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
     mainVFM.add(mMapField);
   }'

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ..first of all congrats @Nequta , you fond solution but one major thing I haven't seen in the code you are not calculating lat/long on  new Thread ...it's really necessary for the application to keep lat/long calc on another thread besids UI thread(Main Thread) ...according to you this code is work fine in simulator , try this on device may be you will get some strange results ..because in simulator you already gave lat/long that's why simulator taking no time to responds ..but in device you will experience that your app is hang ..while lat/long calc ..

Comment: I do not use a simulator to test, only a device. and this is in a thread guys. Thanks for all the responses :)